# JavaScript - Setting Domain of Cookie to IP Address With Port

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I am using a script that creates multiple cookies based off what a users submits through a form. When I attempt to process the data and create a cookie, no cookie is made using my local IP address such as `192.176.22.36` . Yet when I use a domain like `example.com` no cookie is created. There is no issue with my IP as the `window.location` works perfectly.

Below is the script I am using:

```
document.cookie = "entrees=" + entrees + " ; path=/; domain=192.176.22.36:8082";
document.cookie = "fruitsVegetables1=" + fruitsVegetablesArray[0] + "; path=/; domain=192.176.22.36:8082";
if (fruitsVegetablesArray[1] != null) {
    document.cookie = "fruitsVegetables2=" + fruitsVegetablesArray[1] + "; path=/; domain=192.176.22.36:8082";
}
document.cookie = "beverages=" + beverages + "; path=/; domain=192.176.22.36:8082";

// Disable Orders
document.cookie = "orderDisabled=true; path=/; domain=192.176.22.36:8082";

// Go to Order Placed page
event.preventDefault();
window.location = "http://192.176.22.36:8082/order-placed/";
```

Comment: Browser same origin policy rules are applied to the *text* of the URL. What is the URL of the main page?

Comment: The main page's URL is 192.176.22.36:8082/ @Pointy

Comment: What happens if you don't include a `domain=` clause at all? The default value for the domain will be the current page's domain anyway.

Comment: Worked! Thanks @Pointy